# If Jesus's mother's name is Miriam, why is it written Mary in copies of the Quran?

Tags: quran, maryam

The real name if the mother of Jesus Christ is Miriam. Why has the Quran copied the wrong name Mary when it should say her real name Miriam?

Comment: On a side-note, Jesus is also not the "real" name, the Arabic is *'Isa*, the Syriac is  *Ishoʕ* and the Hebrew is *Yeshua*. But convention is to translate it as Jesus because that is the more recognizable word in English.

Answer (score 3):

Like Yousef (in Hebrew) or Yusuf (in Arabic) becomes Joseph in English, Miriam or Maryam becomes Mary in English. The Quran never says Mary, only some translations put it there. If you listen to some Quran recitations, you will hear them say Maryam, not Mary. Also, a verse related to this:

> *Among them there is indeed a group who twist their tongues while (reading) the Book, so that you may deem it to be from the Book, while it is not from the Book. They say, “It is from Allah”, while it is not from Allah; and they tell lies about Allah knowingly.* (3:78)

This is true for all books, the Quran, the Torah, the Bible (which is not considered as a holy book), and even other scriptures, that people while debating about it twist the words or do not have proper knowledge about the book say that the book actually says that. If that translator said that that is actually the Quran’s words, then he is wrong, as no translation gets to the level of the Quran’s explanation. Only the pure Arabic form has the exact words of God.

Answer (score 2):

The Quran hasn't copied or mentioned a wrong name "Mary". In Quran the mother of Jesus is mentioned by the name Maryam. Chaptor 19 of the [Quran](https://quran.com/19) is named after her. Which is similar to the one you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The Quran calls her "Maryam" which is basically an arabicized pronounciation of "Miriam".

Maybe you have this perception that the Quran calls her "Mary" because many translations write her name as "Mary" because it is the common English way of referring to the mother of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the English "Mary" and Latin "Maria" are derived from the Aramaic Maryam (which is the same as in Arabic), which is in turn the Hebrew Miriam.